# Magento2 - how to set item specific delivery dates in same order

Tags: magento2

Is it possible to choose different delivery dates for some products alone if they exists in cart? Is Multi-shipping the way to achieve this?

```
On the Admin panel, click 
Stores > Configuration > Sales > Multishipping Settings > Allow Shipping to Multiple Addresses = "Yes"
```

Please advice on how to achieve this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can not be done without writing a custom module to override the delivery process. The Multishipping Setting only allows you to deliver your products (more than 1 product or more than 1 quantity for the same product) to different addresses only.

Comment: Okay, Is there a way to programmatically do this?

Comment: There are custom modules available for this but even those are 1 delivery date for all the products. Yes, that module can be purchased and customized to achieve this delivery date per item based. (https://www.magedelight.com/delivery-date-magento-2.html?gclid=EAIaIQobChMInOTV-cuY5AIVSyQrCh0UNAneEAAYASAAEgLXBfD_BwE)   

Second thing, we can create custom module from scratch to add "delivery date" when adding an item into the cart to save the date, and show in invoice, order everywhere to know the system and delivery guys.